# Undeleting a deleted user

Tags: users

I have deleted a subscriber and now everything is gone that I had on my website!

How do I 'undelete' him?

Comment: Btw, I am new here, so apologies it this is a silly question… I would appreciate any help!

Comment: How do you mean *gone*. Did this subscriber had special capabilities. What was his role?

Comment: Do you have backups?

Comment: No I don't have back ups… I don't even know this subscriber, I just deleted him, as he constantly was sending me scams…. now all the info on my website is gone, just theme left. :((

Comment: what have you lost exactly when you say everything is gone ?

Comment: I have lost home page information, services information, but weird enough I just discovered that contact page stayed and some other bits.

Comment: How is this possible, that deleting a subscriber, who I don't even know, can loose me so much info?

Comment: & it's not the info only, it's the columns, the design, everything… it's empty pages with theme only left. Very unrealistic.